# Containerized web app on iIS

Tags: docker, containers

Is there a way to deploy a containerized say .net core web app to IIS on a web server and use things like docker swarm and a virtual load balancer.

Am I looking at this all wrong? Would IIS even factor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go down this path, IIS does run in a (Windows) container, however most web apps I’ve seen uses Kestrel as the application web server (I.e. the default netcore images) and some kind of reverse proxy in front (Nginx, HAproxy) to handle things like load balancing, SSL termination and serving of static content.

I think the use case for IIS (though I haven’t used it so I may be wrong here) is to serve legacy ASP.net applications in a containerized environment.

See:
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/

Comment: This may be out of the scope of the scope of the question but i create windows container with IIS on a physical server then how would i tell it what my web address is? ie www.MYSITE.com

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi You need to configure your webapp's base url for that. I don't see that having anything to do with IIS or Docker, it is a matter of configuring the router in your web app.